# React jest enzyme function called test

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I have a simple component I need to test:

MyComponent.js-----

```
import React from 'react';
const MyComponent = (props) => {

  onClickHandler = () => {
     console.log('clicked');
     props.outsideClickHandler();
  }

  return (
     <div>
        <span className='some-button' onClick={onClickHandler}></span>
     </div>
  );
}
```

MyComponent.test.js----

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
    const onClickHandler = jest.fn();

    it('calls click event', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
      wrapper.find('.some-button').simulate('click');
      expect(onClickHandler.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);  // tried this first
      expect(onClickHandler).toBeCalled(); // tried this next
    });
});
```

Tried above two types of expect, my console log value is coming

```
console.log('clicked'); comes
```

but my test fails and I get this:

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: 1
Received: 0
```

Comment: can you do a codesandbox?

Comment: your `onClickHandler` is not tied to `<MyComponent />` in any way, so it won't be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem with your code is when you simulate a `click` event, you expect a totally independent mock function to be called. You need to attach the mock function to the component. The best way is using `prototype`. Like this:

```
it('calls click event', () => {
  MyComponent.prototype.onClickHandler = onClickHandler; // <-- add this line
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  wrapper.find('.some-button').simulate('click');
  expect(onClickHandler.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
  expect(onClickHandler).toBeCalled();
  expect(onClickHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // <-- try this as well
});
```

Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1432) for more potential solutions.